# DataGrip diagram not showing table relationships

Tags: mysql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I have been having this odd issue where my DataGrip diagram generations do not showcase the relationships between tables (in other words, the relationship arrows do not appear).

[image]

Here is an image of what I am talking about.

I have been making this DataGrip diagram as such: **Right click on my schema --> Diagrams --> Show Visualization**. The above image is the result every time.

How can I fix this to show the arrows? **And before you ask, I have foreign keys in my schema tables that reference other columns in other tables.**

Comment: Is Primary and Foreign keys are created properly for all of these tables?

Comment: What happens if you create a new database with relations? Do they appear?

Comment: @moscas No, they do not.

Comment: @KKK Yes, they are created properly. Each foreign key is referencing something else from another table correctly, since I checked the schema. Also, I have updated DataGrip to the latest version.

Comment: Please, show the screenshot of the database tree view

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for these. I am using postgres db and seeing the issue with datagram.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue

Comment: @TimSeed could you provide a sample chunk to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that foreign keys are declared properly.

check the column status in database details view on the left side.

If you are using mysql 8 , you might need to add `ENGINE = INNODB` after creating any table.

for example :

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
....
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: if this change solved your problem please , accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. For me, everything worked when using postgresSQL as a database, but when I switched to MYSQL, and after executing the same queries to create the tables in postgresSQL, the relation between the tables weren't showing any more. I used the `Diagramm` tool from `DataGrip` to visualize it.

Then I compared the data types of the tables between my two databases: postgresSQL and MYSQL, I then realized that at the moment when creating my primary key, I used the SERIAL data type, and postgresSQL sets it as INTEGER data type, while MYSQL sets it as BIGINT UNSIGNED.

The queries I used to create the tables in postgresSQL are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE account(
    user_id     SERIAL          PRIMARY KEY,
    username    VARCHAR(50)     UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR(250)    UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_on  TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL,
    last_login  TIMESTAMP
);
CREATE TABLE job(
    job_id      SERIAL          PRIMARY KEY,
    job_name    VARCHAR(200)    UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
# now a table which connects the two above
CREATE TABLE account_job(
    user_id     INTEGER     REFERENCES  account(user_id),
    job_id      INTEGER     REFERENCES  job(job_id),
    hire_date   TIMESTAMP
);
```

This query executes without errors while using PostgresSQL and MYSQL, but for MYSQL, the relation between the tables won't display or won't work.

I had to change the last command of the query as follow:

```sql
CREATE TABLE account_job(
    user_id     BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)   REFERENCES account(user_id),
    job_id      BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (job_id)    REFERENCES job(job_id),
    hire_date   TIMESTAMP
);
```

Note that the syntax of the command is different and that the data type is no longer INTEGER, but BIGINT UNSIGNED.

After doing these changes, my problem was solved. I hope this helps anyone facing the same problem.